# How to display clickable RGB image similar to pyqtgraph ImageView?

Tags: python, image, qt, mouseevent, pyqtgraph

Despite not being a proficient GUI programmer, I figured out how to use the pyqtgraph module's ImageView function to display an image that I can pan/zoom and click on to get precise pixel coordinates. The complete code is given below. The only problem is that ImageView can apparently only display a single-channel (monochrome) image.

My question: How do I do EXACTLY the same thing as this program (ignoring histogram, norm, and ROI features, which I don't really need), but with the option to display a true color image (e.g., the original JPEG photo)?

```
    import numpy as np
    from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
    import pyqtgraph as pg
    import matplotlib.image as mpimg

    # Load image from disk and reorient it for viewing

    fname = 'R0000187.JPG'    # This can be any photo image file
    photo=np.array(mpimg.imread(fname))
    photo = photo.transpose()
    # select for red color and extract as monochrome image
    img = photo[0,:,:]  # WHAT IF I WANT TO DISPLAY THE ORIGINAL RGB IMAGE?

    # Create app
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])

    ## Create window with ImageView widget
    win = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    win.resize(1200,800)
    imv = pg.ImageView()
    win.setCentralWidget(imv)
    win.show()
    win.setWindowTitle(fname)


    ## Display the data 
    imv.setImage(img)

    def click(event):
        event.accept()  
        pos = event.pos()
        print (int(pos.x()),int(pos.y()))

    imv.getImageItem().mouseClickEvent = click

    ## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode.
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        import sys
        if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
            QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Comment: It'd be better if you remove the parts about panning. Only the part about colour matters to the question.

Comment: I respectfully disagree.  I know how to display static color images, but not within a package that also provides built-in convenient panning,  zooming, and use of the mouse to get pixel coordinates.  The precise point of this question is whether there exists a framework (or programming trick) that allows me to easily do ALL of these things without needing at least twice as many lines of code and eight times as much GUI programming knowledge. If such a seemingly obvious combination simply doesn't exist, that will answer my question.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but surely it's enough to state you're using Qt. I'm just saying it might be better to shorten the code and its preceding text a bit. I don't personally know Qt so I can't really say, though.

Answer (score 3):

`pyqtgraph.ImageView` does support rgb / rgba images. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
data = np.random.randint(255, size=(100, 100, 3))
pg.image(data)
```

..and if you want to display the exact image data without automatic level adjustment:

```
pg.image(data, levels=(0, 255))
```

Comment: 1) For some reason, the example you give doesn't work for me -- it flashes a window on the screen that then immediately disappears, so I can't tell how it's rendering the image.

2) My experience with my own code I posted at the top is that, if I pass the full image (e.g., use img = photo) it displays the rgb image rendered as monochrome, not as color. This is not what I would personally consider "supporting" rgb display.  Does it behave differently in other environments?

Comment: 1) You either need to run this in an interactive python shell (PyQt4 only; this does not work with PySide) or add `QtGui.QApplication.exec_()` to the end of the script. 2) What is the shape of the color image array you are passing to the ImageView? It must be (W, H, 3) or (W, H, 4).

Comment: 1) Adding the QtGui.QApplication.exec_() statement solved the first problem (I also had to add 'from pyqtgraph import QtGui').
2) You're right; the shape was wrong in my original attempt. I should have been using 
photon = photo.transpose([1,0,2]) 
to keep the RGB in the last dimension.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Luke, ImageView() *does* display RGB, provided the correct array shape is passed.  In my sample program, I should have used photo.transpose([1,0,2]) to keep the RGB in the last dimension rather than just photo.transpose().   When ImageView is confronted with an array of dimension (3, W, H), it treats the array as a video consisting of 3 monochrome images, with a slider at the bottom to select the frame.

(Corrected to incorporate followup comment by Luke, below)

Comment: Correction: pyqtgraph.ImageView interprets an array shaped (3, W, H) as a three-frame video. You should see a time slider appear at the bottom for this data.